# Scenarios in which String.Intern should be used?

Tags: c#

When should we consider using String.Intern in C#, keeping in mind its performance considerations that the memory is occupied for these String objects till CLR terminates it?

Comment: See the top voted answer on this question (which isn't marked as the accepted answer) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054471/string-interning-in-net-framework-what-are-the-benefits-and-when-to-use-inter It is unlikely that you'll need to worry about this implementation detail in your own code.

Comment: For an excellent explanation of strings in CLR and string interning and string pools just go and read this blog post from one of the c# creators Eric Lippert: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/09/28/string-interning-and-string-empty.aspx

Comment: This is more on the lines of what I was looking at.
[string.intern usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054471/string-interning-in-net-framework-what-are-the-benefits-and-when-to-use-inter)